# Laravel показывать ошибку 500 с кодом 200

Tags: php, laravel, http

В данный момент при обращении например на не существующий массив выдает ошибку 500.
Я хочу делать так чтобы при ошибке код http был 200, но при этом чтобы лог записал ошибку.

Возможно такое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос непонятен, но попробуйте так:

```
//подключаем для логирования ошибки

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

try {
    //тут ваш код в котором возможно исключение
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //логируем ошибку что бы потом обработать
    Log::info('$e');

    //затем отправляем ок ( === 200)
    return response()->json("ok");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам надо обернуть исключение в `try/catch`, чтобы отловить этот момент. Далее в [laravel есть конструкция](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses) как `response('Hello World', 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain'`.

Суть в том, что вы должны поймать исключение, в catch сделать ответ с нужным кодом.

Comment: А как это обернуть на весь проект сразу ? или на конкретный route

Comment: Делаю так:         
try{  это для ошибки
} catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo 11;
            die();
        }
возвращает опять 500 без 11

Comment: @FəqanÇələbizadə можно в `error handler` сделать. Либо кастомизировать как-то его